# login without form submit

Tags: symfony

I was looking and looking a bit too long time for a solution for my problem and I can hardly find anything focused on the topic which bothers me.

Namely: Do you have any idea if user login can be processed inside symfony2 without using a form login? To be more precise, I mean let's say something like this:

```
$this->authenticationManager->login($user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword());
```

For now I have two ideas to do what I want to do but a bit differently:

1. Take advantage of AJAX and send arequest via POST to loginAction with it (unfortunately this is not going to work if JavaScript would have been disabled)
2. In symfony's docs I found an option **post_only: true** which when I set to false lets me access loginAction wih GET method so simple redirect would have done the job here.

nevertheless I would prefer the solution I'm searching for.

**BTW:** Can you tell me how to generate csrf token if I needed it to successfully submit login data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually set the authentification token:

```
// Inside an action, for example. You already need an user.
$providerKey = 'main'; // your firewall name
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Found [here](http://knplabs.fr/blog/redirect-after-registration-in-symfony2).